# How to get speed in android app using Location

Tags: android, location

I have an issue related to the speed of the vehicle, I am calling `getSpeed` function from `Location` library but always get 0. I'm also using a custom function for getting the location but bad luck, please help me!!!

Thanks in advance for your kind reply.

Comment: show your full code , post here

Comment: in my code i am using "location.getSpeed" function

Comment: post code please

Comment: `float speed = (float) (location.getSpeed() * 18 / 5);` please check this